# Make UIImageView a 'Window' into the Image, Not Squeeze It? Only Shows Small Section

Tags: uiimageview, photo, crop

I've got a UIImageView which gets image from the camera;

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

How do I make it so the image does not squeeze into the UIImageview, but rather acts as a 'window' so you only see a certain section of the image, that is the size of my UIImageView?

Thanks for any help, all is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

will centre the image in the view, you can adjust the size of the view then to hide or show more.

Comment: Will probably also need to mask to bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  My code now looks like this, - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
} - but the image now fills up the whole screen rather than the small box I used for my UIImageView.  How do I add a mask?  Thanks!

Comment: I see you've answered this as correct but none the less, you need to click you image view so it doesn't draw outside it's bounds. Add  clipsToBounds:YES